# iOS Floating Video Window like Youtube App

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

Does anyone know of any existing library, or any techniques on how to get the same effect as is found on the Youtube App.

The video can be "minimised" and hovers at the bottom of the screen - which can then be swiped to close or touched to re-maximised.

See:

Video Playing Normally: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8c1ntfkkp4pc4q/2014-06-07%2001.19.20.png

Video Minimized: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0syp3infu21g08/2014-06-07%2001.19.27.png

(Notice how the video is now in a small floating window on the bottom right of the screen).

Anyone have any idea how this was achieved, and if there are any existing tutorials or libraries that can be used to get this same effect?

Comment: I like this effect too, but no need for a library.  The MP player's view behaves like an ordinary view.  Attach a swipe down recognizer and animate it's position and frame and your app will be as cool as google's

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It sounded fun, so I looked at youtube.  The video looks like it plays in a 16:9 box at the top, with a "see also" list below.  When user minimizes the video, the player drops to the lower right corner along with the "see also" view.  At the same time, that "see also" view fades to transparent.

1) Setup the views like that and created outlets.  Here's what it looks like in IB.  (Note that the two containers are siblings)

[image]

2) Give the video view a swipe up and swipe down gesture recognizer:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *tallMpContainer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mpContainer;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDown:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUp:)];

    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;

    [self.mpContainer addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];
    [self.mpContainer addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];
}

- (void)swipeDown:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    [self minimizeMp:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)swipeUp:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    [self minimizeMp:NO animated:YES];
}
```

3) And then a method to know about the current state, and change the current state.

```
- (BOOL)mpIsMinimized {
    return self.tallMpContainer.frame.origin.y > 0;
}

- (void)minimizeMp:(BOOL)minimized animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if ([self mpIsMinimized] == minimized) return;

    CGRect tallContainerFrame, containerFrame;
    CGFloat tallContainerAlpha;

    if (minimized) {
        CGFloat mpWidth = 160;
        CGFloat mpHeight = 90; // 160:90 == 16:9

        CGFloat x = 320-mpWidth;
        CGFloat y = self.view.bounds.size.height - mpHeight;

        tallContainerFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, 320, self.view.bounds.size.height);
        containerFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, mpWidth, mpHeight);
        tallContainerAlpha = 0.0;

    } else {
        tallContainerFrame = self.view.bounds;
        containerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180);
        tallContainerAlpha = 1.0;
    }

    NSTimeInterval duration = (animated)? 0.5 : 0.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.tallMpContainer.frame = tallContainerFrame;
        self.mpContainer.frame = containerFrame;
        self.tallMpContainer.alpha = tallContainerAlpha;
    }];
}
```

I didn't add video to this project, but it should just drop in.  Make the mpContainer the parent view of the MPMoviePlayerController's view and it should look pretty cool.

Comment: hi. I want to ask what is tallMpContainer. **The view below** MpContainer or **all the view behind MpContainer that fix with screen bounds**?

Comment: Tested in swift 4, [self mpIsMinimized] == minimized) always return true..

Comment: @famfamfam, tallMpContainer is the first child of the view controller's main view and a sibling to mpContainer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a swift 3 version for the answer @danh had provided earlier.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107949/1211470

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tallMpContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mpContainer: UIView!

    var swipeDown: UISwipeGestureRecognizer?
    var swipeUp: UISwipeGestureRecognizer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeDownAction))

        swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeUpAction))

        swipeDown?.direction = .down
        swipeUp?.direction = .up

        self.mpContainer.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown!)
        self.mpContainer.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp!)
    }

    @objc func swipeDownAction() {
        minimizeWindow(minimized: true, animated: true)
    }

    @objc func swipeUpAction() {
        minimizeWindow(minimized: false, animated: true)
    }

    func isMinimized() -> Bool {
        return CGFloat((self.tallMpContainer?.frame.origin.y)!) > CGFloat(20)
    }

    func minimizeWindow(minimized: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if isMinimized() == minimized {
            return
        }

        var tallContainerFrame: CGRect
        var containerFrame: CGRect

        var tallContainerAlpha: CGFloat

        if minimized == true {

            let mpWidth: CGFloat = 160
            let mpHeight: CGFloat = 90

            let x: CGFloat = 320-mpWidth
            let y: CGFloat = self.view.bounds.size.height - mpHeight;

            tallContainerFrame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 320, height: self.view.bounds.size.height)
            containerFrame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: mpWidth, height: mpHeight)
            tallContainerAlpha = 0.0

        } else {

            tallContainerFrame = self.view.bounds
            containerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 180)
            tallContainerAlpha = 1.0

        }

        let duration: TimeInterval = (animated) ? 0.5 : 0.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            self.tallMpContainer.frame = tallContainerFrame
            self.mpContainer.frame = containerFrame
            self.tallMpContainer.alpha = tallContainerAlpha
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: No, sorry, I did not create any demo for this. I just created and tested it locally.