# How to create a floating player like youtube application in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm creating an iOS video application where I would like to show a mini video player, when the user navigates to other view controllers of the application.

Just like what the youtube application has, as shown in the picture below!
How to create a video player which floats on top of all views ?
Any samples available ?

[image]

Comment: See topic [click here][1]

hope to help you, Thank you!

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092414/ios-floating-video-window-like-youtube-app

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you can create that style UITableView. When user touched a specific thumbnail, copy the thumbnail on tableview's superview and move as dragging. If you want, you can change the thumbnail to movie player with fade-in effect.

It might be not that difficult.