# Custom View at the bottom of navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to add a custom view just below the bottom of navigation bar. My requirement is that when certain condition meets, I need to show a view of 80 height which needs to be sticky, for all remaining subsequent screens. Its like what music streaming apps pandora, Spotify have it when you start playing a song but it is at the bottom, but I need to have a view at the top. Any helps

Comment: And what is your question in the post? I don't see any. The post just tells us you have a programming task.

Comment: What have you tried? Think of an idea, work on it, and then ask if you face problems implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely certain about all the mechanics of how you would do it, but You may want to start by adding the view that will have this sticky content to the root viewController or navigationController, and do it like suggested in this post:

[iOS Floating Video Window like Youtube App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092414/ios-floating-video-window-like-youtube-app)

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how I solved it, but instead of custom view at top, I end up showing at bottom only, requirements changed. To do that I was maintaining a root view controller which has tab bar inside it, and it also has custom view, so it was easy to manage that by this hierarchy, as root view controller can easily show and hide the view, and also it remains persistent irrespective which tab user go. But I still don't know how to do at top, which was original requirement.