# floating video player like youtube player

Tags: ios, swift, video, youtube, ios9

I am trying to create an app that search/watch video and I would like to have a floating video player like youtube player app but I am not sure how to do it. I would like that video player to be always visible even if user is navigating around within the app. Could someone please show me some code example how to do it in Swift 2?
[image]

Comment: Did you see this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092414/ios-floating-video-window-like-youtube-app

Comment: well, yes, I kinda looked at it but it was in objective-c, so I got scared away.... Maybe I should try to understand the code example in objective-c and ported over to my project.

Comment: I made a very similar one in Swift. It's draggable and you can customize it. It's avaiable on [SwiftYouTubeFloatingPlayer](https://github.com/hanappaula/SwiftYouTubeFloatingPlayer). Hope it helps you!