# Gesture-driven animation between frames

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to create an interactive animation between a thumbnail frame and a fullscreen frame. Panning upwards could cause the frame to go grow in both dimensions (until reaching fullscreen) while panning downwards does the opposite. Very similar to how Youtube animates their video player.

I tried using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, and a `POPSpringAnimation` that activates when the recognizers state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`, like so:

```
- (void)didPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint point = [recognizer translationInView:self.view.superview];
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y + point.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view.superview];
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view.superview];
        // Initaite POPSpringAnimation using velocity and target frame
        // either fullscreen or thumbnail
    }
}
```

The effect of this is that the view's center gets updated while panning, but its size will only start changing after you stop panning. I do not want to manually resize the frame in `didPan:` without knowing at what ratio to do it.

How can I create a panning-driven animation that simply goes from frame A to frame B?

[This](https://github.com/tfrank64/TFSwipeShrink) framework does almost the same thing, but the animation is not interactive. Same thing goes for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092414/ios-floating-video-window-like-youtube-app) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, a class addd in iOS 10. It lets you pretty easily pause, reverse, or scrub animations back and forth.

I have a demo project on GitHub (Written in Swift, which might be harder for you to follow, since you're using Objective-C:

https://github.com/DuncanMC/UIViewPropertyAnimator-test

The class is actually pretty easy to use. You should be able to figure it out from the docs, and the sample project could at least serve as a roadmap on the APIs to use even if you can't follow the code line-by-line

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there any way to respect the velocity of a gesture recognizer? In your example, flicking the slider causes the animation to stop as soon as you take your finger off of it. Both frameworks like POP as well as UIView's animation methods have support for initializing an animation with an initial velocity, but I can not find any support for such a thing in UIView​Property​Animator?

Comment: Sliders don't keep moving when you remove your finger. They don't have a concept of velocity. You'd have to build your own control that does what you want, and then figure out how to control the animation to make it do what you want. Would you want it to run at a constant speed after a flick gesture, or decelerate?

Comment: Actually, I found that you could use velocity by passing an instance of UISpringTimingParameters to the UIViewPropertyAnimator. Works great now, thanks. UISpringTimingParameters has an argument for initialVelocity.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you used UISpringTimingParameters? In my limited experiments with UIViewPropertyAnimator "scrubbing" a spring animation ignored the spring effect and simply did a linear animation from the start to end position.

Comment: I can make a small blog post about it and share it here.

Comment: https://medium.com/@daniel_larsson/interactive-animations-with-uiviewpropertyanimator-284580951c62

Comment: A gesture recognizer is a better choice if you want to support flicking to force the animation to run to completion since you can figure out velocity with a gesture recognizer. Not so with a slider, as I said in my previous comment.